# What is TExternalThread? "Cannot terminate externally created thread" when terminating a thread-based timer

Tags: delphi, multithreading, delphi-2010, external

This happens half of the time when closing my application in which I have placed a TLMDHiTimer on my form in design time, Enabled set to true.
In my OnFormClose event, I call MyLMDHiTimer.Enabled := false. When this is called, I sometimes (about half of the time) get this exception.

I debugged and stepped into the call and found that it is line 246 in LMDTimer.pas that gives this error.

```
FThread.Terminate;
```

I am using the latest version of LMDTools. I did a complete reinstall of LMD tools before the weekend and have removed and re-added the component to the form properly as well.

From what I've found, this has something to do with TExternalThread, but there's no documentation on it from Embarcadero and I haven't found anything referencing it within the LMDTools source code.

Using fully updated RAD Studio 2010, Delphi 2010.

What really upsets me here is that there's no documentation whatsoever. Google yeilds **one** result that actually talks about it, in which someone says that the error is caused by trying to terminate a TExternalThread.
But looking at the source-code for this LMDHiTimer, not once does it aim to do anything but create a regular TThread.
The one google result I could find, [Thread: Cannot terminate an externally created thread?](https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?messageID=84674)  on Embarcadero mentions using GetCurrentThread() and GetCurrentThreadId() to get the data necessary to hook on to an existing thread, but the TLMDHiTimer does no such thing. It just creates its own TThread descendant with its own Create() constructor (overridden of course, and calls inherited at the start of the constructor)

So... What the heck is this TExternalThread? Has anyone else run into this kind of exception? And perhaps figured out a solution or workaround?
I've asked almost the exact same question to LMDTools' own support, but it can't hurt to ask in multiple places.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 12):

TExternalThread wraps a thread that the Delphi RTL didn't create. It might represent a thread belonging to the OS thread pool, or maybe a thread created by another DLL in your program. Since the thread is executing code that doesn't belong to the associated TExternalThread class, the Terminate method has no way to notify the thread that you want it to stop.

A Delphi TThread object would set its Terminated property to True, and the Execute method that got overridden would be expected to check that property periodically, but since this thread is non-Delphi code, there is no Execute method, and any Terminated property only came into existence *after* the thread code was already written someplace else (not by overriding Execute).

The newsgroup thread suggests what's probably happening in your case:

> ... you have corrupted memory that causes the TThread.FExternalThread member to become a non-zero value.

It might be due to a bug in the component library, or it could be due to a bug in your own code. You can use the debugger's *data breakpoints* to try to find out. Set a breakpoint in the timer's thread's constructor. When your program pauses there, use the "Add Breakpoint" command on the Run menu to add a data breakpoint using the address of the new object's FExternalThread field. Thereafter, if that field's value changes, the debugger will pause and show you what changed it. (The data breakpoint will get reset each time you run the program because the IDE assumes the object won't get allocated at the same address each time.)

Comment: I did as you said, but the only time this breakpoint is triggered is upon the destruction of the component at the closing of the application.

I hit Shift+F7 to trace to the next step in the source code (using debug dcus, so I get to see all the underlying delphi classes too) and the call stack looks as follows:

http://pastebin.org/88904

That looks to me like it's just doing the regular destruction of form components.

Comment: The call stack you show is not the destruction of the timer component. It looks like it's the destruction of some form. Was the FExternalThread field still False? What new value did that memory contain when the data breakpoint triggered?

Comment: Yes, it looks to be the destruction of my application's main form. The Timer component is placed on it, which makes me interpret the call stack as the component being destroyed during the form's destruction (the form should destroy all components on it during destruction, right?)

It seems that when I evaluate the value of the address of FExternalThread, it always comes up as true, even when the delphi debugger itself says that it is false.
I write down @FExternalThread and do
Boolean($Addess) in evaluation and get 'true' even during creation when just FExternalThread returns 'false'.

Comment: Actually, no, nevermind. I managed to propertly retrieve the value at the time the data breakpoint is triggered using PBoolean($address)^ and it is indeed set to true.

Edit: Nope, happens on other computers too so it's supposedly something in this app I guess?

Still, it's weird that the data breakpoint only triggers during destruction and the data is at that time already altered.

So my value has been changed without my application changing it?
I'm gonna have to try running this app on another computer to see if the same error happens there too.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaand I ran it on a different computer, no difference.
I just stepped through my code down to the very last line of my application's .dproj and found that the value at the address of FExternalThread during the creation of the thread is false the entire time :/

Comment: Plus 1 for bug in freeing resources. I ran into this issue when I had incorrect handle closing code.

Answer (score 5):

Is there any chance the code might be trying to Terminate an already Destroyed TThread?  This could easily happen if you have FreeOnTerminate set.

I noticed your post while diagnosing a similar (opposite?) error, "Cannot call Start on a running or suspended thread" in the constructor of a component placed on the main form.  When I removed the Start(), that error was replaced by more telling errors, e.g. "invalid pointer operation" and "access violation", in the corresponding destructor.  The component was trying to manipulate its TThread object after the TThread was Freed, thus leaving things up to Murphy's law.  When I fixed that, I was able to replace the Start() call without the "Cannot call Start" error returning.

By analogy, could your problem be that the address of your FExternalThread had been recycled and clobbered before the destructor/Terminate call?  In our case, we had a buggy implementation of the [Singleton Instance Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Traditional_simple_way); but again, FreeOnTerminate also seems like a likely suspect.

[FYI: I'm using I'm using C++ under RAD Studio XE]